# Stokes's law of sound attenuation and mechanisms of sound absorption

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

According to [this website](https://www.sfu.ca/sonic-studio-webdav/handbook/Sound_Propagation.html) and [this website](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Absorption/Absorption.html), there are two mechanisms by which sound is absorbed in air: effects of viscosity and molecular relaxation.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27s_law_of_sound_attenuation), Stokes's law of sound attenuation is said to describe "the attenuation of sound in a Newtonian fluid, such as water or air, due to the fluid's viscosity", which leads me to believe that Stokes's law describes the first mechanism of sound absorption, but I haven't been able to find an equation describing the second mechanism (molecular relaxation).

So which mechanism of sound absorption does Stokes's law describe? Or does it take both mechanisms into account?